# NumericUpDownExtender for MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How we can use NumericUpDownExtender in MVC4??
Is there is a JQuery plugin for this or another option.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jquery.numeric plugin : http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

it covers also textareas.

Another 3rd party option specifically for MVC is to use Devexpress Spin Edit, which is very good but also very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

`JQuery UI` has a plugin that called `Spinner`; it enhances a text input for entering numeric values, with up/down buttons and arrow key handling.

You can find all information about that at http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

There is a also a Nuget package at http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQueryUIHelpers.Mvc4 that  integrates jQuery UI into your ASP.NET MVC 4 application.